# Azure DevOps always build off of a specific branch if exists

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to make Azure DevOps build from a specific branch if it exists and ignore the trigger branch ? if not just falls back to the default triggering branch ?

For example:

if and RC branch exists always built out off of it.
else build out off of the triggering branch

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - pipeline/*
      - rc/  <<<<<<<<<<< always use this if exists and ignore the trigger
      - integration
      - master
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make Azure DevOps build from a specific branch if it exists and ignore the trigger branch ? if not just falls back to the default triggering branch ?

Yes. The method is exists. You can use Rest API: [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to check if the branch exists.

Then you can use `- checkout：` to checkout the target repo branch. If the branch exists, you can hardcode the branch name. Refer to this doc: [Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref)

Example:

```
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@features/tools
```

You can use [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages)  to confirm which branch to checkout.

Here is a YAML example:

```
trigger:
- master

    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apis/git/repositories/RepoID/refs?api-version=7.0"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(system.accesstoken))"))
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
      
      $count = 0
      
      Foreach($Refname in $response.value.name)
      
      {
         echo $Refname
      
         if($Refname -eq "refs/heads/rc")
         {
            $count = $count + 1
         }
      }
      
      if ($count -eq 1 )
      {
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchexists]true"
      }
      
      else
      {
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchexists]false"
      }

- script:  echo $(branchexists)

- checkout:  git://azure/countly-sample-ios.git@test
  condition: eq(variables['branchexists'], 'true') 
- checkout: self
  condition: eq(variables['branchexists'], 'false')
```

**Reuslt:**

When the branch exists, it will always checkout the existing branch.

For example:

[image]

Or it will checkout the trigger branch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. the only thing I would add is that the RepoID is actually the repoName. At least that was not clear for me.